# how to replace or delete non alphabetic characters like './','>' using SED?

Tags: regex, sed

How can I replace or delete non alphabetic characters like `'./','>'` using SED?

Comment: Something like `sed 's/[^a-z]//gi'`?

Comment: Removed tag, formatting, still not clear what he wants

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]//g' file
```

or perhaps what you mean is :

```
sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g' file
```

Which will preserve spaces/tabs etc.

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, potong! The link you posted has a lot of good stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]//g'
```

...which translates to (in English): replace every occurrence that is not in the alphabet, with nothing.

Regex [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) match any character or group of characters you specify between the square brackets. If the first item in the brackets is the "^" character, this tells the regex engine that the character class is a negation, meaning that any character(s) specified by the rest of the character class should not be matched, but anything else should.

So in my solution, I am saying "match all lower case and upper case alphabetic letters" and then negate that.

The "g" at the end of the command means: match all occurrences, not just the first one. Without it, only the first non-alphabetic character would be removed.

Of course you can replace the "nothing" between the last two forward slashes to be whatever you would like to replace the non-alphabetic characters with.

Comment: Thank you! It's so simple when you know the answer, but it could be a mystery when you don't...